# deliver c++ application for the final customer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-installer

I am working on a c++ windows application on visual studio 2010.

I want to deliver my application to my customer so he can use it easly, without the obligation of installing visual runtime fx. And to be executed every where.

How do I set up the installer so that the customer does not need to separately install any required Visual Studio runtime libraries?

Please i want a solution for this problem, because my costumers are so far from computing, they love just "next, next, install, finish" system.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've done my best to try to "fix" your question to what I think you are asking, but it probably still is going to end up getting closed.

Comment: I'd guess it depends on what installer tool you are using. There probably are packaged installers for the runtimes that you can use as parts.

Comment: If you're reasonably competent with C++ and Visual Studio 2010, utting together an MSI install package should be sraight-forward. The Windows SDK and Visual Studio both include examples of how to distribute your application to the target host.

Comment: I suggest searching Programmers Exchange: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ and Super Users: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the options are static linking, private deployment,  consuming merge modules to reuse someone elses logic or redistributing a prereq via the use of a bootstrapper.

It's impossible to give an exact answer without knowing what your exact dependencies are but here's the pro's and con's for each:

static linking - Easy as there is nothing to deploy other then your file.  Major downside is if the library has a security vunerablity and needs to be patched, you can't without rebuilding and redeploying your application.

private deployment - Relatively easy as you just deploy the file in your application directory.  Still has servicing issues as you have to rebuild and redeploy your application. Microsoft won't patch your directory.

merge module - Seems easy, just add the merge module.  There are still major problems though in that if there is a problem with the merge module you are at the mercy of the vendor. (Microsoft).   This is why the use of merge modules is frowned upon these days.

redist -  Hardest to implement ( you need a setup.exe bootstrapper defined )  but also easiest in that you reuse someone else's installer.  This is optimal since that vendor can then patch that dll without rebuilding yours.

So generally, redists are the way to go.  But not always... :)

Comment: This is an excellent answer: thorough, clean and easy to read.

Comment: Really? I figured I'd lose everyone when I mention prereq and bootstrappers without explaining what they are. :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you have two options:

- Build an installer (using, for example, WiX or NSIS). The installer would install your application along with any required libraries. Since you are distributing your application, chances that you are building an installer already, and so this solution makes sense.
- Statically link your file with any required libraries. That way, your application executable includes all the code that it needs. This, of course, assumes that the libraries that you are using can be statically linked. That may not be the case.

Answer (score 2):

You either statically link your product so that it doesn't have any external dependencies, or you include the MSI [Merge Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the runtime components you need when you build the installer.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't statically link anything. If you are producing MSI installers, just include the merge modules for the Visual Studio runtime as described [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_vcredist.htm) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/02/13/building-an-msi-using-wix-v3-0-that-includes-the-vc-8-0-runtime-merge-modules.aspx). If you can use a recent enought version of WiX, you may want to create a [bundle](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm).